# Matlab minimization problem: finding a hole in a flat surface

Tags: matlab, minimization

My 2D objective function is like finding a whirlpool in the surface of a lake.  I do not have good initial guesses.  Below example is in the middle of the surface but it may be anywhere on the surface and the diamerter may be smaller than shown in the example.

[image]

I was thinking that MATLAB fminsearch would work but if the initial guess is on the flat surface, it will go a short distance then  stop (shown by the dots on the left which increase in size as iteration count goes up.).
I was thinking that if I could increase the multiplier of the search (1.05 by default), I could better set up the problem with an initial guess in the center of the surface and a large spread of the trial points.  But I find that there is no option to change the multiplier used in fminsearch.
Does anyone have a suggestion for how to better approach this minimization problem in MATLAB?

Comment: Why not evaluate the function at a lot of points, and use the point with the lowest value as the start point for your `fminsearch` code?

Comment: Like @CrisLuengo said, you can first fo a course grid search and use the lowest value as an initial guess for the optimizer; Not to difficult to write yourself, or you can use [`MultiStart`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/multistart.html).

Comment: In minimization problems, the starting point is always important. But when you don't have any idea where to start you could always set-up up several uniformly distributed points in the solution space (as is done in heuristic optimization) and see which is enough to find the solution.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to Multistart.  I was not aware of it.